# Possible to enable only vertical scrolling (N/S) on compass scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, mousewheel

I want to allow only North/ South vertical scrolling and disable all other directions.

I'm using this code which works perfectly for disabling all directions since it just disables the middle button on the mousewheel that activates compass scrolling.

```
$('body').mousedown(function(e){if(e.button==1)return false});
```

However, the ability for the user to click the middle button and smooth scroll North  /South would be a nice feature to keep.

Is that possible?

Comment: Why would you want to explicitly disable a scroll method? Just make your content only scrollable vertically. (`overflow-x: none;` in CSS)

Comment: @Bergi Thanks but that was tried early on and has zero effect on autoscroll AKA compass scroll.

Comment: How would it scroll if there is nothing to scroll? I don't get the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @Bergi Therein lies the mystery.